# Plugin NOT Triggering on Pre-Validation Delete on N:1 record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a plugin registered in Pre-Validation to be able to retrive some other data during the delete operation as Pre-Operation will diassociate the record from others and does NOT return any data. The problem is the Plugin is NOT triggering when I delete it from a subgrid of its parent. Any idea why?

Comment: How have you verified that it is NOT triggering as opposed to just not working?

Comment: I have verified that it is NOT triggering as I have a logging from the Plugin. Every Step the plugin is doing it is written to a file.

Comment: What method did you use to verify it is not triggering? Can you post some code and a screen grab of the registration? Pre-Delete plugins are supported so either the plugin is not registered correctly or there is an issue with the plugin code.

Comment: There is NO issue with the plugin code or registration as when I register it in Pre-Operation mode it is triggering fine But it is NOT triggering in Pre-Validation.

Comment: The record is deleted or deassociated?

Comment: You have to provide us more than just the problem statement to help you. You state it doesn't work when registered on the Delete message in Pre-Validation stage. We know that plugins can be registered on the Delete message in Pre-Validation stage and execute successfully. Therefore, without seeing your code and registration we are just guessing. But my guess is a bug in your code because Pre-Val is different than Pre-Op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually in my code as I am using Developer toolkit I changed the registration from Pre-Operation to Pre-Validation and forgot to change the code from 20 to 10 as shown below: `base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(20, "Delete", "Contact", new Action<LocalPluginContext>`